# "I need a cup of tea to revive <me> <myself>"

Tags: reflexive-pronouns

[macmillandictionary.com](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/revive):
**(1)** *I need a cup of tea to revive **me**!*
my variant:
**(2)** *I need a cup of tea to revive **myself**!*

What's the difference between them?

Comment: "Myself" is better. This is a standard, textbook use of the reflexive pronoun as direct object of verb.

Comment: I can't see any reason to suppose it's "better" to use the explicitly reflexive pronoun. It's not like you need it to clarify the meaning. The general principle is nearly always "Simplest is best", and [*according to this NGram*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=drink+to+loosen+me%2Cdrink+to+loosen+myself&year_start=1960&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) we're much more likely to use the "flat" pronoun in the same context with *[I need a] **drink to loosen me***.

Comment: This question reminds me of how I discovered many years ago that some managers in companies I worked for seriously believed it was useful to analyze how many *different* coding constructions their programmers used (on the basis that "More is better"). After that I always made a point of telling them the truth was probably the *opposite*. Variation for the sake of it is usually at best pointless (and at worst seriously confusing) for both programming *and* natural languages.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Can I hop in and play devil's advocate? There's a case to be made that a programmer who uses hashmaps for everything is probably not doing better than a programmer who uses hashmaps when hashmaps suit the problem at hand, and heaps for other problems, and some other data structure for yet other problems. Or with a metaphor: there is a toolbox, there are different problems - being able to choose the most-approriate tool can be better than always using the one tool one is most familiar with.

Comment: @Stef: Indeed. Most pithily summarised by [*If Your Only Tool is a Hammer, Every Problem Looks Like a Nail*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/if_all_you_have_is_a_hammer,_everything_looks_like_a_nail)!

Answer (score 5):

There's no difference in meaning, and [both forms are in common use...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=drink%20to%20calm%20me%2Cdrink%20to%20calm%20myself&year_start=1960&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

[image]

At least a few of the non-reflexive matches will be preceded by a main clause whose subject is *not* the speaker *(**John** poured a drink to calm **me**)*, where the reflexive form doesn't work. But that won't be enough to affect the main message of the chart.

---

There's no debate about the choice with...

> 1: *I need **to drink** to calm **myself***
> 2: *I need **a counselor** to calm **me***

Linguistically speaking, the speaker is both "agent" and "patient" in #1, but ***counselor*** introduces an "external" agent in #2. That's primarily what determines whether we use a reflexive pronoun or not. And ***a cup of tea*** falls somewhere in between those two relationships, making "reflexiveness" a stylistic choice.

---

TL;DR: This isn't a context where you *need* to use a reflexive pronoun. So make life easy (for *yourself!* :) and don't bother with it.

Comment: I'm not trying to win an argument here. Anyone can use whichever version they like. I'm just pointing out that *many* (majority, or significant minority, who cares?) native speakers don't bother with the reflexive form. Why would a learner want to learn when he ***can*** use it, if that just means he now has to watch out for contexts where he ***can't*** use it? Such as my ***John** poured a drink...* example above.

Comment: "Why would you bother with more than the bare minimum?" is a weird take on a learning platform.

Comment: How are you so certain that "that won't be enough to affect the main message of the chart"? The "[other person] poured a drink to calm me" usage seems like it would be much more common than the "I poured a drink to calm me" usage.

Comment: @ToivoSäwén: Okay, I admit using that chart was lazy. As a native speaker, I know perfectly well that the non-reflexive pronoun is fine in OP's *exact* context - but the *reason* for this is a bit tricky to pin down. Realistically there's no debate about the choice with #1: *I need **to drink** to calm **myself***  and #2: *I need **a counselor** to calm **me***. Linguistically speaking, speaker is both "agent" and "patient" in #1, but ***counselor*** is a third-part agent in #2. And ***a cup of tea*** falls somewhere in between those two relationships, so "reflexive" is a stylistic choice.

Comment: While "a drink to calm myself" may, technically be correct and acceptable, to me (a native American English speaker), it would immediately flag the speaker as either a non-native speaker or the rather pompous [Charles Emerson Winchester III](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Ogden_Stiers#M*A*S*H_(1977%E2%80%931983)).

Comment: @FreeMan: If by "may technically be **correct** and acceptable" you mean to imply that there's some objective standard by which we can evaluate the syntax, with ***only one choice*** being "correct", then I vehemently disagree. In many cases, that "choice of plurality" is a ***stylistic choice*** - where some people might have strong opinions for or against either version, and others might attach no significance to it at all.

Comment: Just pointing out that (despite the n-gram) "myself", when used in this context, is not all that common in spoken use, at least in the Midwestern US. I agree that it's use _is_ correct, just not common 'round these parts. Perhaps it's more common in British English with which I am less familiar.

Comment: @FreeMan: Yeah, well, some Americans use slightly weird "reflexive" constructions. Interestingly, Google Books has exactly *one* instance of [*I'm gonna ... eat **me** some chicken*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22eat+me+some+chicken%22) and one instance of [*I'm going to go eat **myself** some chicken.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22eat+myself+some+chicken%22) As a Brit, I don't really have an opinion as to which version there is "less weird". But I expect you do! :)

Comment: "eat me some..." is a very Southern US thing. Fun to say on occasion, usually making fun of others when doing so. ;)

Answer (score 5):

The two sentences look similar and have similar functions, but the grammar is quite different.

In the first sentence, the grammatical structure is *[ "need" + object + "to" + base form ]* meaning roughly, *need the object to do that action*. So this sentence means something like, "*A cup of tea can revive me*, and I need that to happen." There's no *reflexive* here, because the tea is doing the action, not the subject. The subject, "I" merely needs the tea to do its job. Also, there's nothing about *purpose*, which there is in the second sentence.

There are two separate grammatical structures in the second sentence: *[ "need" + object ]* and *[ "(in order) to" + base form ]*. The first simply indicates a need for an object, and the second indicates *purpose*. So that sentence means something like, "*I want to revive myself*, and I need a cup of tea in order to do that." Here, the action is reflexive because the subject "I" wants to do something to themselves, and requires a cup of tea.

Comment: The second interpretation is of course _also_ possible with the non-reflexive pronoun: “In order [for some general notion] to revive me, I need a cup of tea” vs “In order [for me] to revive myself, I need a cup of tea”. The tea example is a bit contrived in the non-reflexive sense here; a more natural-sounding parallel would be, “We need friends to make us happy”, where it's the reflexive version (“We need friends to make ourselves happy”) that's less natural.

Comment: I think in something like *I need a **physiotherapist** to loosen **me / myself** up*, choosing to use the reflexive form implies speaker thinks of himself as the primary motivator. So ***he uses the physiotherapist*** to achieve his goal, as opposed to ***the physiotherapist helping him***.